# Ghost image when stopPlayback() called on VideoView

Tags: android, android-videoview

I noticed that on certain devices, when I call the method `stopPlayback()` on a VideoView, the last image is still displayed on the screen.  So if anyone has an idea on how to handle it and make this image disappear (without changing the visibility of the View or destroying it), I would be very grateful.

Answer (score 0):

You could extend `VideoView` and override `stopPlayback()` to fill the View with black, or whatever you want displayed upon stopping (after calling `super.stopPlayback()`, of course).

Comment: Thanks for your idea, but for me it 's pretty the same as changing the visibility to INVISIBLE. I can't do that because when I restart the video, when I set the visibility to VISIBLE (or withdraw the black color), the last image is still visible for a short time.
I'd prefer (if it's possible) to have the same "standart" behavior on every device.

Comment: @AdrienThiebault You shouldn't "withdraw the black color" (I'm not sure how you would, anyway...) Just fill the View with black upon stopping and let starting take care of itself.  I'm not suggesting adding a layer of black on *top* of the View.